# Returning access_token back to client vs SPA + PKCE

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, pkce

Whenever a question is asked about returning access_token to the client, the idea is discouraged. The reasons mentioned are typically, tokens can be intercepted when in transit or can be stolen from browser storage. However, PKCE flow exactly does this. Both access_token and refresh_token (although with less lifetime) are returned to the client. How is this flow any more secure than a web server returning access_token?

Answer (score 0):

PKCE make the task of intercepting more complex by adding a code, which must be generated by the client at the time of initialization of the PKCE flow and this code is known only by the trusted client.
The PKCE is more secure than just returning the access_token by several things for example the callback must be registered in case of PKCE, in other terms the response will be sent just to the trusted client that is registered in the identity provider, and there is many other advantages of PKCE that you can found in the specification